# Scilab - calling another GUI within a GUI. Functions not working

Tags: function, user-interface, scilab

I'm quite new to scilab, I have created two GUIs (see example below), with script 2 being called from script 1. However the function in script 2 don't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Script 1

```
'//////////
f=figure('figure_position',[0,0],'figure_size',[1250,650]);
//////////
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('File'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('?'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('Tools'))
toolbar(f.figure_id,'off')

handles.dummy = 0 ;

handles.exam=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',        [0.5,1,1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[14],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','bold','ForegroundColor',[0,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.5,0.5,0.1,0.05],'Relief','flat','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','exam','Style','pushbutton','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','obj102','Callback','exam_callback(handles)')

function exam_callback(handles)
close(f);
clear
exec('costs0-1.sce',-1) ; 
endfunction`
```

Script 2

```
////////// Defining the figure (size, name etc)/////////////////////////////
f=figure('figure_position',[0,0],'figure_size',[1250,650],'auto_resize','on','background',[8]);

//////////
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('File'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('?'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('Tools'))
toolbar(f.figure_id,'off')



//Cabinet - TEXT
handles.obj17=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[1,1,1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal','ForegroundColor',[0,0,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.15,0.93,0.1,0.05],'Relief','flat','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Cabinet','Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','obj17','Callback','')

// Cabinet - POP UP MENU
handles.service=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[0.8,0.8,0.8],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal','ForegroundColor',[0,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.25,0.93,0.15,0.05],'Relief','flat','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','1|2','Style','popupmenu','Value',[1],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','service','Callback','service_callback(handles)')


// CALCULATE  PUSHBUTTON
handles.Calculate=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[0,0.8,0],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[16],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','bold','ForegroundColor',[0,0,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.22,0.02,0.15,0.08],'Relief','raised','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','CALCULATE','Style','pushbutton','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','Calculate','Callback','Calculate_callback(handles)')

 // Resources- TEXT
 handles.Resourcestxt=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[1,1,1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[14],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','bold','ForegroundColor',[0,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.75,0.95,0.20,0.05],'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Resources in hours','Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','','Callback','')

// TOTAL hours - TEXT
handles.totalhourstxt=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[1,1,1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[14],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','bold','ForegroundColor',[0,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.75,0.75,0.12,0.05],'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Total Hours','Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','','Callback','')

// hardware hours  - text
handles.totalhours=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',[0.95,1,1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','helvetica','FontSize',[14],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','bold','ForegroundColor',[0,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.88,0.75,0.08,0.05],'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','','Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','totalhours','Callback','')

function Calculate_callback(handles)
if handles.service.value == 1 then
resource_hrs = 2
end

if handles.service.value == 2 then
resource_hrs = 10
end

set(handles.totalhours,'String',string(resource_hrs));

endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

It is a scoping problem. When function `exam_callback()` gets called it runs the other script with `exec('costs0-1.sce',-1)`.
In that script you define the function `Calculate_callback(handles)`. This goes out of scope and is deleted when  `exam_callback()` is finished and as such can't be called when the button is pressed.

The second problem is that the handles are not globally affected, so when leaving `exam_callback()` the handles of the second Cost Gui are not added to `handles`.

### Solution

You can move the generating of the GUI into a function `createCostGui()` and then load script2 at the start of script1 with `exec('costs0-1.sce',-1);`.

To make `Calculate_callback(handles)` function discard the handles argument and use the tags to find the handles

```
function Calculate_callback()

    serviceHandle = findobj('tag','service');

    if serviceHandle.value == 1 then
        resource_hrs = 2
    end

    if serviceHandle.value == 2 then
        resource_hrs = 10
    end

    totalHoursHandle = findobj('tag','totalhours');

    set(totalHoursHandle,'String',string(resource_hrs));

endfunction
```

### Further remarks

Text elements are generally static and thus don't need a Callback argument.
If you want an argument to stay at its default value, you don't need to specify them.

From the [Scilab documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/uicontrol.html):

> h = uicontrol(PropertyName, PropertyValue,...) creates an uicontrol and assigns the specified properties and values to it. It assigns the default values to any properties you do not specify. The default uicontrol style is a "Pushbutton". The default parent is the current figure. See the Properties section for information about these and other properties.

**Small remark on your question**

Next time an error message could help with making your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks very much for the time and effort you gave, that worked great!